# Flaws of Green, Schwarz, Witten's Superstring Theory?

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, education

While trying to find a good string theory book to read as an introduction to the subject, I found people saying that the two-volume series *Superstring Theory* by Green, Schwarz, and Witten is an outdated series, and so is not appropriate to be used as a primary textbook for an introduction to string theory. However, these people did not go into detail as to what exactly was outdated about these books, and how would one be disadvantaged if they used this series as their first introduction to string theory.

So, what exactly would I miss if I used these books as my introduction to string theory?

Comment: Well, it predates the [2nd superstring revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_string_theory#1994%E2%80%932003:_Second_superstring_revolution) in 1995, for starters.